# What is the intuition behind the uniqueness constraint for morphisms determining products?

Tags: category-theory

I am following Bartosz Milewski's book and weblectures and have a question about the definition of the categorical product.

He uses names that are a bit different from the ones I can find on Google, so here is the definition. An object $c$ is the product of objects $a$ and $b$ (just denoted $c$, not $a \times b$) if it has the projections $p : c \rightarrow a$ and $q : c \rightarrow b$ such that for any object $c'$ together with projections $p' : c' \rightarrow a$ and $q' : c' \rightarrow b$ there exists an ***unique*** morphism $m : c' \rightarrow c$ *that make the triangle commute*, i.e. such that $p \cdot m = p'$ and $q \cdot m = q'$, i.e. "there exists only one of them that makes the triangles commute".

Now, what is the intuition behind this uniqueness constraint? **I'm not looking for a counterexample, but for the "reason" behind it**. What happens when we drop the uniqueness constraint? I know that if we do we satisfy all requirements for $a = a, b = b, c = a \times a \times b, c' = a \times b$, which we should not be able to. When we drop the uniqueness constraint, we allow for the situation that the morphism $m$ "makes up" something by selecting some random value for the unused $a$.

Can we state something about this in terms of bounds or entropy? I.e. something like 'a product is the "lowest-information situation" possible while still having all information available to be general enough to always satisfy the laws' or something like that? Like some greatest lower bound? An by enforcing $m$ to be unique we ensure that it cannot "add entropy/information" in any way?

Edit: I guess what I'm asking is: what is the consequence of one object having an unique mapping to another? If a morphism $a \rightarrow b$ is unique, what does this tell us about the information content of $a$ and $b$? Surely $a$ is "bigger"/contains more information than $b$, right? Doesn't $b$ even have to be a singleton in this sitution?

Edit2: OK let me reformulate my question. When we look at the object that forms the product, we are looking at the /smallest possible object/ that still satisfies all laws. Any bigger object we can "shave down" to this most basic object, and still retrieve the two components. Dually, when defining a sum, we want the most general object possible, any instantiation we can generalize. **We define these greatest lower bounds and least upper bounds trough saying there must be an *unique* morphism between them.** My question: how does the uniqueness of a morphism say anything about the size of the objects at its beginning and end?

Comment: you want to make your constructions functorial, and for that you need the uniqueness, otherwise your construction won't define a functor, for example in triangulated categories you have that problem, and it messes up a lot and was one of the reasons to study dg categories with functorial cones

Comment: Ok, but is there a more intuitive "solution"? Something like "If there are multiple morphisms $a \rightarrow b$ then it cannot be a product, because {that means b is bigger than a which it should not be/we can make up information which we should not be able to/etc/...}" instead of a "otherwise our category theory rules break/do not apply" argument?

Comment: well, if category theoretic rules break stuff will become very messy as it being a functor precisely means it is well behaved and one has a certain minimum of control. (i.e. precisely what you said is encoded in there)

Comment: Please understand that it being a functor means nothing to me at this stage. I'm just looking for an intuition maybe in set theory that describes what a non-unique morphism would look like in set theory, and argues that by requiring $m$ to be unique we get rid of the exact situations *within set theory*.

Comment: it being a functor essentially means it is well behaved with respect to morphisms. It essentially is at the same time a minimality and maximality condition, depending on the nature of universal property you are defining, for example, if you drop it in the definition of a product in a set and you would drop the uniqueness any thing that is contained in the product becomes a product (hope I got the arrows the right way around in my head) for the disjoint union it will give you precisely that everything bigger would be a disjoint union. furthermore it gives you uniqueness of your object up to iso

Comment: So $A=a$ etc. ?

Comment: For a "reason" for defining products like this how about the following. Cartesian products of sets, products of topological spaces, direct products of modules all satisfy it in their appropriate categories. And in a partially ordered set (considered as a category) products and coproducts are glbs and lubs resp.

Comment: I understand that this way we define glb and lub. However, why does having an *unique* morphism $a \rightarrow b$ mean that one is bigger or smaller than the other?

Comment: The way products are defined makes sure that maps into the product are are equivalent to pairs of maps into the factors. In other words, we want to have $\hom(x, a\times b)=\hom(x,a)\times \hom(x,b)$ where the product on the right hand side is just the usual product of sets. In that regard, categorical products aren't really that different from products of sets.

Answer (score 5):

When you define **the** product (not **a** product) of $X$ and $Y$, you are in fact defining 4 things at the same time:

1. $X \times Y$
2. $\pi_1 : X \times Y \; \to \; X$
3. $\pi_2 : X \times Y \; \to \; Y$
4. $\langle f, g \rangle$, for any $Z$, $f : Z \to X$ and $g : Z \to Y$

Those things must be unique or else this wouldn't be a definition for **the** product.

The unicity for the second, third and fourth things is expressed with equality. While the unicity for the first thing is expressed with isomorphism, because in category theory we are only interested in objects up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that a map into a product should be entirely determined by its coordinates.

Why do we want that ? Well products are supposed to generalize the usual cartesian products of sets, groups, topological products, where an element is indeed entirely determined by its coordinates; and therefore so are the maps into the product.

You can check out my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401919/in-category-theory-why-do-we-define-the-product-by-its-universal-property-the-w/3401968#3401968), which is more generally about why we define the product the way we do, in particular this should motivate the uniqueness.

But I think the "points in a product have coordinates that determine them"-view is a good way to see categorical products

Answer (score 3):

I want to address your edits first. A priori, categories have no notion of size, entropy, or information. You would need to formulate such a thing.

One possibility is by considering presheaves and the Yoneda embedding. I realize that these concepts will likely be unfamiliar to you right now, but they may help future visitors, including potentially yourself.

**First reason for why we define products this way**

Because this is the property that the Cartesian product of sets satisfies.

**Brief review of presheaves and the Yoneda embedding**

A presheaf on a category $\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand\op{\text{op}}\C$ is a functor $\C^\op\to \newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\Set$. 
The category of presheaves on $\C$ has presheaves for objects and natural transformations as morphisms, and is denoted $[\C^\op,\Set]$.

There is a canonical fully-faithful functor $y:\C\to [\C^\op,\Set]$ defined by 
$y(x) = \C(-,x)$.

We can therefore view $y(x)$ as translating an abstract object into a collection of sets that we can measure the size of, and thus regard this as a sort of measure of the information contained in $x$.

**Back to products**

If $c$ has morphisms $p:c\to a$, and $q:c\to b$, then we can define a morphism
$y(c)\to y(a)\times y(b)$, where $y(a)\times y(b)$ means the pointwise cartesian product of sets (which is also the categorical product of the functors).

The morphism is defined as follows. Given $f\in y(c)(x) = \C(x,c)$, 
$p\circ f : x\to a$ and $q\circ f : x\to b$, so defining 
$f\mapsto (pf,qf)$ makes sense, and you can check that this is in fact natural.

Call this morphism $\phi_{p,q} : y(c)\to y(a)\times y(b)$. 
The existence requirement translates into the statement that $\phi_{p,q}$ is (pointwise) surjective, and the uniqueness requirement translates into the statement that $\phi_{p,q}$ is (pointwise) injective. The two together become the statement that $\phi_{p,q}$ is an isomorphism. In a metaphorical sense, $c$ encodes the cartesian product of the information of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Chapter 7 of https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/GentleIntro.pdf . In §7.2 I spend some time pre-categorially motivating a general idea of what makes for (something that will play the role of) a product, which in turn motivates §7.3 which gives the standard categorial definition of a product in a very natural way, including that uniqueness requirement.

Comment: If the two downvotes are from people who think the line taken in those notes is *misguided* or downright *wrong*, I'd certainly be interested to know why!

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware you're not looking for a counterexample, but the following is too long for a comment and might still be an interesting case to consider in the context of this question:

Consider the category of *probabilistic mappings*, where objects are measure spaces $X,Y,Z,\ldots$ and morphisms are Markov kernels / probabilistic mappings: So for $f: X\to Y$, $f(x)$ isn't necessarily uniquely defined, but rather a probability distribution on $Y$.

First observation: What are points in this category? A morphism $f: \ast\to X$ is simply a probability distribution on $X$.

Second observation: The category encompasses the category of measure spaces since any deterministic mapping can be viewed as a probabilistic mapping.

Now, consider the product measure space $X\times Y$ with its projections onto $X,Y$. Does this turn it into a product in the category of probabilistic mappings? For this to be true, we should have $\text{Hom}(\ast,X\times Y)\stackrel{\cong}{\to}\text{Hom}(\ast,X)\times\text{Hom}(\ast,Y)$, which would mean that probability distributions on $X\times Y$ are in 1-1 correspondence with pairs of probability distributions on $X,Y$.

That's of course not true: There are distributions on $X\times Y$ whose coordinate distributions aren't *independent*, and those don't come from a pair of probability distributions on $X,Y$. Yet, every pair of probability distributions on $X,Y$ comes from a probability distributions on $X\times Y$, namely the product distribution.

So $\text{Hom}(\ast,X\times Y){\to}\text{Hom}(\ast,X)\times\text{Hom}(\ast,Y)$ *is* indeed surjective, but not injective / uniqueness fails.

Comment: Downvoter (d|c)are to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the uniqueness requirement means you won't be able to proof the product's uniqueness up to isomorphism. Indeed, let me sketch the proof that *the* product is, in fact, isomorphic to any other product.

Let $A$ and $B$ be some types. Assume $X, \pi^X_A, \pi^X_B$ and $Y, \pi^Y_A, \pi^Y_B$ are two products, i.e. $\pi^X_A \in Hom(X, A)$ and similarly for $\pi^X_B, \pi^Y_A, \pi^Y_B$. Additionally, call $m^X_M \in Hom(M, X)$ / $m^Y_M \in Hom(M, Y)$ the unique morphism into $X$/$Y$, for a type $M$ with projections into $A$ and $B$.

How to show that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic? Well, certainly, we get a morphism $X \to Y$ by the universal property for $Y$, i.e. $m^Y_X \in Hom(X, Y)$ and also $m^Y_X \in Hom(Y, X)$. What remains to be shown is that these two are mutual inverses: $m^Y_X \circ m^X_Y = id_Y$ and $m^X_Y \circ m^Y_X = id_X$.

Here is where uniqueness comes into play. Since both $m^X_Y \circ m^Y_X$ and $id_X$ are morphisms in $Hom(X, X)$ and $X$ itself fulfills the conditions to invoke the universal property and this property says that *the morphism is unique* we have, by the uniqueness of $m^X_X$:

$id_X = m^X_X = m^X_Y \circ m^Y_X$

Similarly we can proof $id_Y = m^Y_X \circ m^X_Y$, which concludes the proof that the two objects are isomorphic.

So far, only the uniqueness of $m^X_X$ and $m^Y_Y$ has been used. But the two products are not proven fully isomorphic yet.  What remains to be shown is that the structure of them, i.e. the projections and their universal property, agree when transporting along the isomorphism. For that we have to show:

$
\pi^X_A = \pi^Y_A \circ m^Y_X \\
\pi^X_B = \pi^Y_B \circ m^Y_X \\
m^Y_M = m^Y_X \circ m^X_M, \text{for all $M$ with correct shape}
$

The first two are easy, they are in fact given again by the universal property for $Y$, invoked for taking $M = X$. The last line, then, would be impossible, were it not for the uniqueness property that immediately let's us conclude the proof since $m^Y_X \circ m^X_M \in Hom(M, Y)$.

Answer (score -2):

I thought about it some more, and have been able to come up with an explination such that it makes sense for me.

When we relate morphisms to set theory, if we have an unique $f :: a \to b$, it means $f$ is surjective: it uses the entire codomain. As functions cannot map one element in the domain to multiple elements in the codomain, it means that $a$ is *at least as big as* $b$. Now, if we require no further conditions, we eventually morph into the smallest set satisfying no conditions, i.e. the empty set. However, if we set some requirements, we eventually morph into *the smallest set still satisfying the conditions*. This is how a product is defined: the smallest set such that you can construct both parts again, i.e. their union *without any extra information*. Even more specific: all elements of $a$ and $b$ must be in $a \times b$ as otherwise the conditions will not hold. Furthermore, no additional elements can be inside $a \times b$ because otherwise there would be an *unique* mapping from it to the set that does not contain this additional element, i.e. it would not be the smallest.

The dual applies for the sum: here we are looking for the biggest set such that it still satisfies the conditions.